# R, ifelse error: invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, if-statement

I am using the newest version of R (I am new to R, just got it last week, learning to plot graphs with it).

My code:

```
df$bins <- ifelse(df$ROW_A <= 0.1, "0-0.1",
 ifelse(df$ROW_A <= 0.5, "0.1-0.5",
 ifelse(df$ROW_A<=1, "0.5-1",
 ifelse(df$ROW_A <= 2, "1-2",
 ifelse(df$ROW_A <=5, "2-5",
 ifelse(df$ROW_A <=10, "5-10",
 ifelse(df$ROW_A >10, ">10","NA")))))))
```

I kept getting an error:

> Error in +ifelse(df$ROW_A > 10, ">10", "NA") :    invalid argument to
> unary operator

Can anyone kindly advise me what went wrong please?

Comment: As an alternative to the endless ifelse blocks you can use `cut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative you can use `cut`:

```
df$bins <- cut(df$ROW_A, breaks = c(0, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, Inf), 
               labels = c("0-0.1", "0.1-0.5",  "0.5-1", "1-2", "2-5", "5-10", ">10"))
```